# calling functions gives 2 different values of output

Tags: c++, c

This has had me very confused for a few days. I am somewhat new to C but I can usually figure things out by googling but this has me stumped. I've asked a few people and they haven't been able to help me.

The problem is that when I include the line I've marked in my code (48 and 49), f1 calculates output to be different from output2 even though they should be mathematically the same. However, if I call it in a different way then I don't have this problem. I'm compiling on ubuntu 12.04 with gcc or g++ (both give the same problem).

I've also uploaded the code to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qsgXTyjG). See lines 48 and 49 for the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PARAMETER1 100
#define nx1 5
#define nx2 10
#define nx3 10
#define ny1 4
#define ny2 5
#define ny3 10
#define Nx nx1+nx2+nx3+1
#define Ny ny1+ny2+ny3+1
#define X1_LENGTH 5.0     
#define X2_LENGTH 10.0
#define X3_LENGTH 50.0
#define Y1_LENGTH 0.04
#define Y2_LENGTH 5.0
#define Y3_LENGTH 20.0

double f(int j,int i);
double g(int j,int i);
double dx(int i);
double calc_value_pos(int i);
double calc_value_neg(int i);
double **matrix;
double f1(int j,int i);
double calc_value2_pos(int i);
double calc_value2_neg(int i);
double f2(int j,int i);

int main(void){

    matrix=(double **)malloc((size_t) ((Ny+1)*(Nx+1)+1)*sizeof(double * ));
    for (int j=1; j<=(Ny+1)*(Nx+1); j++) {
        matrix[j] = (double *)malloc((size_t) ((Ny+1)*(Nx+1)+1)*        sizeof(double ));
    }

    for (int j=1; j<=Ny+1; j++){
        for (int i=1; i<=Nx+1; i++){
            matrix[j][i]=0.0;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<=Nx; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<=Ny; j++){
            int k=i+(j)*(Nx+1)+1;
            matrix[k][k] = f(j,i);      /*including this line causes the problem*/
            //matrix[k][k] = f1(j,i);     /* including this line does not cause the problem*/
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

double f(int j, int i){
    double output=f1(j,i)+f2(j,i);
    return output;
}
double f1(int j, int i){
    double output;
    if (i==0 || j==0 || i==Nx || j==Ny) output=0.0;
    if (i!=0 && j!= 0 && i!= Nx && j!=Ny) {
        output = (g(j,i)*g(j,i+1))/(g(j,i)*calc_value_pos(i)+g(j,i+1)*calc_value_neg(i));
        double output2;
        output2=1.0/( (calc_value_neg(i)/g(j,i)) + (calc_value_pos(i)/g(j,i+1)));
        /*if (output2!=output2) printf("output2: %lf\n",output2);*/
        if (output != output2 && output==output) printf("(j%d,i%d) output:%lf \toutput2:%lf\n",j,i,output,output2);
    }
    if (output!=output) output=0.0;
    return output;
}

double f2(int j,int i){
    /* calculates f2 for (j,i) */
    double output;
    if (j==0 || i==0) output=0.0;
    else output = g(j,i)*g(j,i-1)/(g(j,i)*calc_value2_neg(i)+g(j,i-1)*calc_value2_pos(i));
    if (output!=output) output=0.0;
    return output;
}

double calc_value2_pos(int i){
    /* calculates calc_value2_pos for X=i */
    double output= dx(i)/2.0;
    return output;
}

double calc_value2_neg(int i){
    /* calculates calc_value2_neg for X=i */
    if (i==0) printf("Warning off grid\n");
    double output= dx(i-1)/2.0;
    return output;
}

double g(int j,int i){
    double output=PARAMETER1;
    if (j==0 || i==0) output=0.0;
    if (j>=ny1+1 && j<=ny1+ny2 && i>=1 && i<=nx1) output=0.0;
    if (output!=output) printf("calc_D(%d,%d) error: output==nan\n",j,i);
    return output;
}

double calc_value_pos(int i){
    if (i==Nx) printf("Warning east pos\n");
    double output;
    output = dx(i+1)/2.0;
    if (output!=output) printf("calc_delta_e_pos(%d) error: output==nan\n",i);
    return output;
}

double calc_value_neg(int i){
    double output=dx(i)/2.0;
    if (output!=output) printf("calc_delta_e_neg(%d) error: output==nan\n",i);
    return output;
}

double dx(int i){
    double output;
    if (i<=nx1) output=1.0*X1_LENGTH/nx1;
    if (i<=nx1+nx2 && i>=nx1+1) output=1.0*X2_LENGTH/nx2;
    if (i<=nx1+nx2+nx3 && i>=nx1+nx2+1) output=1.0*X3_LENGTH/nx3;
    if (output!=output) printf("delta_x(%d) error: output==nan\n",i);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this is tagged C++?

Comment: In case it matters, are you using a C or a C++ compiler?

Comment: I've tried using both C and C++ which is why I tagged it in C++

Comment: The problem is that f1 produces 2 different outputs depending on where it is called from

Comment: Could you give some specific examples? What different output is it producing in the two cases?

Comment: This is an aside, but don't you think you've allocated substantially more memory for your matrix than you actually require?  You've created an M*N-by-M*N matrix, and you're using it as M-by-N.

Comment: If you compile it and run it you will see. When f1 is called from f when j=1 to 19 and i=25, output=40 and output2=20. When f1 is called from main output==output2 for those (j,i)

Comment: I compiled and ran it and I get the same value for `output` and `output2` (`33.333333`) no matter which of those two lines in `main` are uncommented.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on why it isn't working like that for me? What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: I am using clang 3.2 on x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, compiling with the flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99`. I have tried optimization levels `-O0` and `-O3` and I get the same results.

Comment: @icktoofay Maybe it's a problem with how gcc or g++ are interpreting my code. Look at the answer below

Comment: With MinGW gcc 4.7.2 I get output!=output2 at -O1 and -O2 but not -O0 or -O3. However the size of the difference is what you'd expect from rounding errors (a few * 1e-15 for values up to about 100) - nothing like `output=40` and `output2=20`.  There's no obvious difference between calling `f` and `f1`.  This is all compiling as C++, using C99 instead gives `output==output2`.

Comment: @MikeDinsdale Do you think this is an issue with my compiler? I'm using gcc & g++ v4.6.3

Comment: @Ben No, it's undefined behaviour, the compiler can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @Ben: No, but Daniel Fischer's got the answer!  Since you're on linux you might want to look into using valgrind - it picks this kind of thing up straight away.

Comment: Thanks I'll get valgrind.

Answer (score 3):

In `calc_value_pos`, for `i == 25`, you call `dx(26)`:

```
double dx(int i){
    double output;
    if (i<=nx1) output=1.0*X1_LENGTH/nx1;
    if (i<=nx1+nx2 && i>=nx1+1) output=1.0*X2_LENGTH/nx2;
    if (i<=nx1+nx2+nx3 && i>=nx1+nx2+1) output=1.0*X3_LENGTH/nx3;
    if (output!=output) printf("delta_x(%d) error: output==nan\n",i);
    return output;
}
```

Now, `26 > nx1 + nx2 + nx3`, thus you return an uninitialised variable, which means undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ahhhhh thanks!! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much! So the different compilers were treating the undefined behavior differently calling the function in different manners produced different results since it was undefined? Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't be absolutely sure, it's UB after all, but probably, the different calling sequences just made different values be left where `output` was allocated when `dx` was called. (And different calling conventions on linux and Windows made it not show up on Windows, apparently.)

Comment: Okay that sort of makes sense. I thought this was some complicated issue that was because I didn't understand how C was doing math. Turns out it's a bug that I missed. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome. (There are the usual minuscule differences between `output` and `output2` for some values due to how floating point math works, but those are one or maybe two ULPs, as can be expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to figure out what this code is doing, but:

```
output = (g(j,i)*g(j,i+1)) / (g(j,i)*calc_value_pos(i)+g(j,i+1)*calc_value_neg(i));
output2= 1.0/( (calc_value_neg(i)/g(j,i)) + (calc_value_pos(i)/g(j,i+1)));
```

It's clear to me why these should be mathematically similar.
from `output2`

```
1.0/( (calc_value_neg(i)/g(j,i)) + (calc_value_pos(i)/g(j,i+1)));
```

So we cross multiply to get a common denominator:

```
1.0/ ((g(j,i+1)*(calc_value_neg(i)) + (g(j,i)*(calc_value_pos(i)))/(g(j,i)*g(j,i+1))
```

1.0 divided by a fraction is equal to that fraction's reciprocal:

```
g(j,i)*g(j,i+1) / (g(j,i+1)*calc_value_neg(i) + g(j,i)*(calc_value_pos(i)) )
```

Which is exactly the same as your output:

```
g(j,i)*g(j,i+1) / (g(j,i)*calc_value_pos(i) + g(j,i+1)*calc_value_neg(i) )
```

So the error isn't in how you're representing the code, it's happening somewhere in the calculation itself.  I can't get this entire block of code into my head for debugging, but 2 things jumped out on the surface:

1. `g(j,i-1)` in f2
2. `f()` is `f1()+f2()`, so why would `f()` be the same as `f1()` unless `f2()` definitely equates to zero?

Have you tried directly casting the 1.0 as a double prior to doing the calculation?  I've run into issues before (albeit not in C) where I've written something like 1.0 and it's been treated by the compiler as a float instead of a double, then the calculation occurs before the casting to double and I get a rounding error.

Try throwing this in:

```
double one_d = 1.0;
output2= one_d/( (calc_value_neg(i)/g(j,i)) + (calc_value_pos(i)/g(j,i+1)));
```

Just a lark, sorry I don't have any better ideas.

Comment: The problem isn't that f1!=f. The problem is that output!=output2. I don't understand why that happens depending on how I am calling it. When f1 is called from in f then output!=output2. When f is called from main output==output2.

Comment: Doing that solved my problem even when I have it set to output3 (that is when I set what you posted to output3, output==output2. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: I understand why if the 1.0 is not cast properly it would give the wrong value but why would that carry over to output when all the math is done with doubles?

Comment: @Ben: Using `1.0d` forces the literal to be a `double`, so you could try using that rather than introducing another variable.

Comment: @icktoofay with 1.0d I still get output=40.0 and output2=20.0